# Decoding protoPayload from Google Logging API

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, google-api-nodejs-client, google-cloud-logging

I want to read BigQuery log entries to do some analysis. But I can't seem to get the `protoPayload.value` decoded. I've tried messing around with the `google-proto-files` and `protocol-buffers` packages, but I think I'm missing something really obvious here...

```
const Logging = require('@google-cloud/logging');
const protobuf = require('protocol-buffers');
const protoFiles = require('google-proto-files');


const protoPath = './node_modules/google-proto-files/google/cloud/audit/audit_log.proto';
const root = protoFiles.loadSync(protoPath)
const AuditLog = root.lookup('google.cloud.audit.AuditLog');

const client = new Logging.v2.LoggingServiceV2Client({ projectId });
client.listLogEntriesStream({resourceNames, filter, pageSize})
    .on('data', entry => {
        console.log(entry); // Entry is of type AuditLog
        console.log(AuditLog.decode(entry.protoPayload.value.buffer));
        process.exit(1)
    })
    .on('error', e => console.error(e))
    .on('end', () => console.info('END RECEIVED', arguments))
```

I do receive messages with protoPayloads, but the error I receive when attempting to decode the message is this:

```
Error: no such Type or Enum 'google.rpc.Status' in Type .google.cloud.audit.AuditLog
```

The actual question: What is the proper way to decode the `protoPayload` field in a `LogEntry`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the `entry.protoPayload.value` is a serialized proto (an AuditLog message) you should be able to handle it with the deserializeBinary() method documented at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#message   That 'protocol-buffers' npm doesn't appear to be from Google, and the proto compiler will generate code for deserializing already.

I wouldn't expect you'd need to, but you could also try loading the "google/rpc/status.proto" definition explicitly.